# Building ternary relationship using Laravel Eloquent Relationships

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relational-database

Have three entities:

- Project
- Employee
- Employment

**Problem description:** Employee can work on many projects and for each he has one employment. I want to have access to all projects and your referred employments of a certain employee.

I'm not sure but the relationship must look like a *ternary*:

[image]

The physical table is not defined yet. So, be free to design (most basic) them.

And my question:

**How i can build using Laravel Eloquent Relationships**?

Comment: your diagram makes no sense, data model is not a workflow. a relation can not be "ternary"

Comment: @NDM why a relation can not be ternary? http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.28.4412&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 4):

Basically your four tables will be something like:

**employee**

- id
- ...your fields

**project**

- id
- ...your fields

**employments**

- id
- ...your fields

**employee_project**

- employee_id
- project_id
- employment_id

You can split the problem in 2 by 2 relations:

```
class Employee extends Model{
  public function projects(){
    return $this->belongsToMany("Project")
  }

  // Second relation is Optional in this case
  public function employments(){
    return $this->belongsToMany("Employment", 'employee_project')
  }
}
```

A Project model

```
class Project extends Model{
  public function employees(){
    return $this->belongsToMany("Employee")
  }

  // Second relation is Optional in this case
  public function employments(){
    return $this->belongsToMany("Employment",'employee_project')
  }
}
```

A Employment model

```
class Employment extends Model{
  public function employees(){
    return $this->belongsToMany("Employee")
  }

  public function projects(){
    return $this->belongsToMany("Project")
  }
}
```

At this point in your controller you can manage your relation, for example if you want to add to $employee, the project with id 1 with the employment with id 2 you can simply

```
$employee->projects()->attach([1 => ['employment_id' => '2']]);
```

I hope this answer to your question.

If you need timestamps in your pivot table, add ->withTimesetamps() to your relationships.

Comment: The `employees()` method of the `Employment` class would look up for a `employee_employment` table. `'employee_project'` would need to be specified in both methods from the `Employment` class, as the second argument.

Answer (score -5):

`Employee` has `Employment`

`Employment` has `Project`